# $51456$, $541456$, $331259$ and $92020$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Ec primes are primes formed by concatenation in base ten of two consecutive Mersenne numbers, $40952047$, for example.

Some exponents leading to an ec prime are: $51456$, $541456$, $331259$ and $92020$.

It is easy to see that $331259=541456+13-210210$ and $92020=331259-239239$.

Now $92020\equiv -25\pmod {449}$

$541456 +13\equiv -25\pmod {449\cdot 201}$

$210210\equiv 78\equiv -239239 \pmod {449}$

$51456$ is a multiple of $201$.

Is it possible that all this has some explanation?

Comment: So surprising those coincidences are , there seems to be no deeper structure in the exponents giving an ec-prime. If we could find better restrictions , we could easier detect them and extend the search limit , but I have no such idea. Tons of candidates remain even if we sieve out the prime factors upto , say , $10^9$. Other structures , like algebraic or aurifeuillan factors seem to not apply here. Someone claimed to have tested them upto $8\cdot 10^5$ (for the case $7k+6$) , but I still have doubts.